How can I search for hotels sorted by Internet quality in a given area?
I'd like to find hotels with the best available Internet in a given area. How can I search for hotels ranked by Internet quality (as assessed by reviews of past customers or some other way) in a given area?
Booking.com has a wifi score but I couldn't find a way to sort hotels based on that wifi score:


I found that even in the same hotel the WIFI quality depends a lot on what room you are in, so you would need A LOT of reviews to get statistically meaningful data.

@Hilmar just a few reviews would suffice to know if wifi is crap everywhere or just in some rooms.

@FranckDernoncourt You have no way of knowing if bad reviews are link to specific rooms or if they are generally bad across the entire hotel.  Doubly so with only a few reviews.

@PeterM meanwhile, Booking.com has a wifi score, so I guess some people look at it.

What’s “best”? Reliable? Very high bandwidth? Actually available? Actually free? Not limited to a single device? No need to reconnect every hour? Also different people have different needs. Some will consider it 10/10 as long as they managed to connect, it was actually free, and they were able to download a few e-mails. Others will consider it crap if it doesn’t deliver 100 Mbit/s both ways. We don’t even know what your actual needs are…

@jcaron "Internet quality (as assessed by reviews of past customers or some other way)"

After a rather thorough search, it seems that currently there  exist no services to sort hotels based on Internet quality.
http://www.hotelwifitest.com/ used to sort hotels based on Internet quality, but the website has shut down:

(Screenshot from thepointsguy.com)
